# Doing two separate operations using single stream

Tags: java, java-stream

Consider the array [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]. I want to compute the sum of even and odd numbers using Java 8 stream.

Currently I am doing it as

```
integers
    .stream()
    .map(integer -> integer % 2 == 0 ? new int[]{integer, 0} : new int[]{0, integer})
    .reduce(new int[]{0, 0}, (a, b) -> new int[]{a[0] + b[0], a[1] + b[1]});
```

This returns an `int[]`. Is there any other way to do the same while returning a list? Is there a better way to write the stream?

Comment: Besides that it's probably possible. Doesn't this look ugly and unreadable as ...?

Comment: Spagetti code, make it more readable.

Comment: Even if you stick to your array approach, you’re much better with `integers .stream() .collect(() -> new int[2], (a,i)->a[i%2]+=i, (a,b)->{ a[0]+=b[0]; a[1]+=b[1]; });`

Comment: @Holger could you please explain `(a,i)->a[i%2]+=i`.

Comment: I suppose you already know that `i%2` is either `0` or `1`, as you are already testing `i%2` against `0` (which implies that `i` is even). So `a[i%2]` is `a[0]` if `i` is even or `a[1]` if `i` is odd. And `variable += expression` is the same as `variable = variable + expression`, which is especially handy for array elements as we don’t need to repeat the array element expression (and the index will be calculated only once). So it’s equivalent to `(a,i)->a[i%2]=a[i%2]+i` which is equivalent to `(a,i)->{ if(i%2==0) a[0]=a[0]+i; else a[1]=a[1]+i; }`